# How to Drill Down on Apparent Corruption

Tags: c++, valgrind, address-sanitizer

I've been working with C and C++ for a fairly long time.  I have a computer science minor.  I'm familiar with the pitfalls intrinsic to the low level access to process memory these languages provide.  I've spent days and weeks in them.

Learning to use `valgrind` about a decade ago was a lifesaver in terms of catching minor access errors and such.  Currently, I also use ASAN with clion, and mistakes of this sort are usually caught and dealt with quickly.

I presume there's no bulletproof, however, and a recent problem has me completely stumped.<sup>1</sup>
I have an object that includes a non-public `sockaddr_storage` field named `from`.  This can be accessed via:

```
const sockaddr_storage* getSockAddr () {
    return &from;
}
```

But the address returned is wrong.  Starting from a breakpoint on the `return` line in `gdb`:

```
Breakpoint 3, socketeering::Socket::getSockAddr (this=0x617000000400) at Socket.hpp:81
81          return &from;
(gdb) p this
$1 = (socketeering::UDPsocket * const) 0x617000000400
(gdb) p &from
$2 = (sockaddr_storage *) 0x617000000600
(gdb) p (const sockaddr_storage*)&from
$3 = (const sockaddr_storage *) 0x617000000600
```

Seems pretty clear the value returned has to be 0x6170000006**00**.  But no:

```
(gdb) fin
Run till exit from #0  socketeering::Socket::getSockAddr (this=0x617000000400) at Socket.hpp:81
0x00000000004290ab in udpHandler::dataReady (this=0x631000014810, iod=0x617000000400, con=0x60e0000249b0) at /opt/cogware/C++/Socketeering2/demo/echo_server.cpp:66
66              auto sa = sock->getSockAddr();
Value returned is $4 = (const sockaddr_storage *) 0x617000000618
                                                              ^^
(gdb) p sock
$5 = (socketeering::UDPsocket *) 0x617000000400
```

That's no good -- it is 18 bytes inside the structure.  Even worse, I CANNOT reproduce it with a simple SSCCE:

```
class foo {
    sockaddr_storage ss;
    public:
        foo () { cout << &ss << "\n"; }
        const sockaddr_storage* getSockAddr () { return &ss; }
};
```

Meaning it's not some misunderstanding of the rules, etc.  It's obviously not a logic error either.

## It has to be corruption, right?

This is a single threaded process, and if instead of `fin` I just keep stepping to see what's happening, there is literally nothing to see.  One step to the function close, and the next one is at the assignment with the wrong value.  *Neither valgrind nor ASAN indicate any hijinx.*

What can I look at to find out what is happening?  Obviously *something* is going wrong here in between:

```
 return &from;
```

And the actual return of a value.  Is looking at assembly dumps for clues the only route left to me (presuming that would help at all, I'm no ASM guy)?

The answer I dread is there's nothing beyond scouring the code for mistakes that valgrind and ASAN didn't catch.  Finding out under what circumstances they would not catch corruption is a starting place for that.

---

1. Which I did raise earlier in a now deleted question.  All any one could say was exactly what I would say if I read a question like that: We need an SSCCE, and the corruption could be in other parts of the code. Point being, there's nothing in the information I have to show which explains the problem, but, sans inviting everyone onto a 10-20K LOC project, that's all I can do.  So what I am asking now is not what's wrong, but *"How can I determine what's wrong?"*

Comment: Didn't we already see this question a few hours earlier?

Comment: Without a [mcve], how do you expect anyone to be able to answer this question?

Comment: The technique I have used with past hard to track down bugs is to start removing code. Eventually you will get to your SSCCE where there is no bug. So at some point after some change the bug will disappear. Chances are good (but not certain) that the last bit of removed code is what is causing the trouble. This isn't a quick solution, but it's a fairly certain one, especially if you can reproduce the bug consistently.

Comment: Are you compiling with or without optimization?  Often gdb has a hard time debugging optimized code, and at the source level you'll see things that appear to be impossible.  Can you reproduce the bug without optimization?  If not, you may find it more helpful to single-step and inspect data at the assembly level.

Comment: And where is it that the *externally observable behavior* of the program actually goes wrong?  Following on the previous point, when debugging optimized code, it's easy to fixate on some behavior that looks obviously wrong and assume it's the cause of your bug; when in fact it may just be a debugger artifact, the code you're staring at is perfectly fine, and the bug is somewhere else entirely.  I have done this many times myself.

Comment: In short, I agree with you that I don't see how the address could actually be corrupted in between the return and the assignment, short of a very unlikely compiler bug - and the debugger output is not really good evidence that this is what's happening.  So I would suspect that this is *not* actually what's happening.

Comment: You say this code is single threaded, but don't sockets use callbacks?  And since the code doing the callback isn't built with valgrind, maybe it wouldn't see bad behavior?  My first thought (based on no facts whatsoever) was something was using a deleted pointer.  Perhaps you could explicitly memset any buffers to 0xff or something as part of deleting them to see if that changes the behavior at all.  Sometimes you just try stuff in hopes that it will teach you something.

Comment: @NateEldredge No, I'm not using optimization (`-O0`).  I've also done this with and without ASAN (which seems to involve some re-arrangement); the error is persistent (always 18 bytes in).  Thanks for that last comment -- this question was almost going to be about my presumptions re corruption, one of which is that this really shouldn't be possible here (corruption) because there's no code executed beyond the return and the assignment. I am now thinking that may be naive in the sense that I can't say unequivocally it isn't true, which maybe that it is a worthwhile question...

Comment: Okay.  Then indeed I think single-stepping the assembly is your best bet: `display/i $pc` and `si`.  I still suspect you'll eventually find that this code is okay.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd WRT to sockets and methodology, there's no external libraries involved and no, POSIX C sockets don't include callbacks -- really this whole thing is a library unto itself, so I implement callbacks (in fact, that's what `udpHandler::dataReady()` is), but using a single threaded async/non-block/poll methodolgy.

Comment: @CodeClown42 `socketeering::Socket` -- So is `from` a non-static member of a class?  If so, do you know if `socketeering::Socket` is valid?  If you want an example, take your attempt at an SSCCE and do this: `int main() { foo *f; f->getSockAddr(); }` -- what do you think will happen?  Even if the example is simple, don't dismiss something like that is causing the issue -- an invalid object being used.  Also, you can't rely on the value of `this` "looking ok" -- an invalid object's `this` value can look as valid as any other value.

Comment: Use UbSan, ASan and valgrind.

Comment: Since you know in advance the place in memory (on the stack) where the unexpected 0x18 value will appear, you could add a watchpoint (with `watch` command in gdb) on that location. Maybe it will give you a hint at the assembler instruction that writes the value, and then you can unravel the problem from there.
Btw. you're using `auto sa` in your code... For debugging I'd definitely replace that by the actual data type that I expect to be used. It's a simple change that removes one source of uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

> Is looking at assembly dumps for clues the only route left to me

Yes, using a `disas` command is the appropriate approach here.

> (presuming that would help at all, I'm no ASM guy)?

Even if you can't *write* assembly, it's often pretty easy to *read* assembly. Especially if it's something like `x86_64` and doesn't involve complicated bit twiddling or floating point. *And* it's a skill that will serve you well.

---

Usually the problem of this sort is a result of an ODR violation: *somewhere* in your program you have a *different* definition of `socketeering::Socket`, one in which the offset between `this` and `from` is `24` (it's not `18` bytes, it's `0x18` bytes!) instead of `0`.

Often such ODR violation comes from using different `#defines` in different parts of the code, e.g.

```
class Socket {
#if defined(TRACING_ON)
  char trace_buf[24];
#endif
  sockaddr_storage from;
};
```

Compile above struct in one `.cc` file with `-DTRACING_ON`, compile another `.cc` without it, link them together into a single binary and BOOM: you may see *exactly* the bug you've described.

Sometimes, the problem comes from not recompiling *all* code (e.g. you may have an old object or a shared library laying around).

It could also come from linking together code built by different compilers, though this is rare (usually if the compilers are not ABI-compatible, they use different name mangling to preclude the program from linking).

Note: if `Socket` inherits from some other class, the difference may be coming from the superclass and not the `Socket` itself.